# Cappuccino cryptic [undefined] errors

Tags: cappuccino

i get this kind of error in cappuccino

```
TypeError: Result of expression '_2b' [undefined] is not an object.
TypeError: Result of expression '_40' [undefined] is not an object.
```

I can't think of what they could be for as they don't specify a line number.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you mentioned, you should load your application using `index-debug.html` while testing. Furthermore you can use Safari's developer tools to break on errors by clicking on the stop sign shaped "pause" button at the bottom of the Javascript debugger. This is helpful if the error message shows up inside of an Objective-J main file and you need to look at the full stack trace to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't realise the index-debug.html which will give me better errors.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: why are you answering 2 year old posts, I have got the hang of SO now.